# Question on Taylor expansion regrading dot product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I happened across this expression in the QM textbook, "The Quantum Mechanics Solver How to Apply Quantum Theory to Modern Physics 3rd edition" (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-13724-3) and I don't quite understand how the author taylor expands this expression provided the condition is $ 
|\boldsymbol{R}| \gg\langle|\boldsymbol{r}|\rangle
$ :

$$
\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{R}-\boldsymbol{r}|}=\left(R^2-2 \boldsymbol{R} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}+r^2\right)^{-1 / 2} \simeq \frac{1}{R}+\frac{\boldsymbol{r} \cdot \boldsymbol{R}}{R^3}
$$

Just inspecting the terms I assume the author is taking the first two terms.

Comment: What exactly is your notation? Is $R = \vert \textbf{R} \vert$? I would rotate both vectors such that you can wlog assume that $\textbf{R} = R e_1$. And yes, we are just take the first two terms.

Comment: Hi, Author only states that $\boldsymbol{R}$ is the position vector from particle to atom and $\boldsymbol{r}$ is position vector from particle to electron.

Comment: Could you say what is "the QM textbook" exactly ?

Comment: Well, then I guess it is safe to assume that what I suggest above is the correct terminology. Hint for the expansion. Rewrite $$ \frac{1}{\vert \textbf{R}-\textbf{r} \vert} = \frac{1}{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\frac{\textbf{r} \cdot \textbf{R}}{R^2} + \left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2}} $$ then expand $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ around $x=0$. That gives you the desired expansion.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven
Thank you! That works nicely, I have a question. Instead of taking R out I took out $(R^2 +r^2)^{0.5}$ resulting in $
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 \frac{\mathrm{r} \cdot \mathrm{R}}{(R^2+r^2)^{0.5}}}}
$ and then Taylor expanded it. However, this doesn't give me the desired $R^3$ as yours does. Why is that?

Comment: Because your expansion is wrong. You can already see this if you take $\textbf{r}, \textbf{R}$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, could you expand a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, it is already late and my brain is no longer working properly. You rewrote it in the correct way. However, if you do it this way, you will need to expand $\sqrt{R^2+r^2}$ as you want to have the expansion in terms of $R$.

Comment: Ah thank you, I also made slight computation error but you are correct! Thank you very much !